# Inheriting forms in Qt with CMake (multiple inheritance method)

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-designer

I imagine this is fairly straight-forward, but I admit I'm not well-versed in CMake (or Qt for that matter), so here's the problem:

I have a form that was built in Qt Designer (with a `.ui` file).  Two classes have been created that are based on this form.  Both classes have a lot of duplicated code.  So, I wanted to create a base class that inherited the `formname.ui` file using the multiple inheritance method to manage that common code.

The problem is that I don't know how to get CMake to build it correctly. Compiling gives me the error `ui_formname.h: No such file or directory`.

I've identified the following elements as necessary to get CMake to buld this correctly:

```
set (UI_HDR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/formname.ui)
QT4_WRAP_UI (COMPONENT_UI_HDR ${UI_HDR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}) #Necessary here?
```

The difference between this and the other two cases is that this cmakefile is not building an executable, whereas in the other two cases, it was.  It may be I'm missing something else, but the lack of an `add_executable` line is the most obvious difference that I can see, as the `COMPONENT_UI_HDR` variable would be included in that list, were it there.

Any suggestions on how to work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.  Indeed, I was right about the "add_executable" difference.  Since this was a library and not an executable, I had to add a reference to the wrapped variable in the add_library call, i.e.:

```
add_library ( ${...} ${COMPONENT_UI_HDR} )
```

Compiled without a hitch...